# How to write Joins using CriteriaUpdate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I would like to request please help me to find out solution for updating the foreign key value in other table.
for example:-

If we taken Device Table

columns are :-   devicename
deviceId
displayname
userId
roomId
isDeleted

other table is Rooms Table

columns are :- roomName
roomId
roomType
isDeleted

Hear it is looking like one-to-many relationship.
i.e., one room will contain many devices.

In the above two tables roomId is primary key in Rooms Table  and  roomId is forgin key in Device Table.
So, Hear what we want is we have to update the roomId in DeviceTable.
I tried but, I cant able to find the solution for this, I request you guys' please help me for this solution.

the database tables will be like

```
Room Table(room_table)

room_id    room_name    room_type
1           ROOM1       ROOM_TYPE1
2           ROOM2       ROOM_TYPE2

Device Table like(device_table)
device_id     device_name    display_name    room_id
1              DEVICE1        DISPLAY1         1
2              DEVICE2        DISPLAY2         2
```

I hope you guys understand the above tables.

So, now Coming to my required task is:-
I want to update roomId in device table i.e., for DEVICE2 we have to update from roomId 1  to roomId 2 AS SHOWN IN BELOW.

```
Device Table like(device_table)
device_id    device_name   display_name    room_id
1             DEVICE1       DISPLAY1         1
2             DEVICE2       DISPLAY2         2
```

for this I wrote java code like:-

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "device_table")
    public class Device {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "device_id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int deviceId;
        @Column(name = "device_name")
        private String deviceName;
        @Column(name = "display_name")
        private String dispalyName;
        @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        //private List<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<>();
        @JoinColumn(name = "ROOM_ID")
        private Room roomList; 
         //setters & getters
    }

        @Entity
        @Table(name = "room_table")
        public class Room {
            @Id
            @Column(name = "room_id")
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private int roomId;
            @Column(name = "room_name")
            private String roomName;
            @Column(name = "room_type")
            private String roomType;
            @OneToMany(mappedBy="roomList")
            private Collection<Device> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
      
    
     //setters & getters
}
```

For updating I tried code like below.

```
public class SaveDataClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
         CriteriaBuilder userBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaUpdate<Device> deviceUpdate = userBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(Device.class);
            Root<Device> deviceUpdateRoot = deviceUpdate.from(Device.class);

            Subquery<Device> deviceSubquery = deviceUpdate.subquery(Device.class);
            Root<Device> roomRoot = deviceSubquery.from(Device.class);
            Join<Device, Room> join = roomRoot.join("roomList", JoinType.LEFT);
            
             deviceUpdate.set(deviceUpdateRoot.get("dispalyName"), "DISPLAY12345"); 
            deviceUpdate.set(join.get("roomId"), 2);
        
            deviceUpdate.where(userBuilder.equal(deviceUpdateRoot.get("deviceName"), "DEVICE2"));
            int returnValue = session.createQuery(deviceUpdate).executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(returnValue);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error like

```
Oct 01, 2020 8:00:03 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Oct 01, 2020 8:00:03 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.roomId'
Oct 01, 2020 8:00:03 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.roomId'
 Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.roomId'
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.LiteralProcessor.lookupConstant(LiteralProcessor.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:1038)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:1026)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.assignment(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1054)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.setClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:765)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.updateStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:381)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3324)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.AbstractManipulationCriteriaQuery$1.buildCompiledQuery(AbstractManipulationCriteriaQuery.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3628)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:203)
    at com.infotech.client.SaveDataClientTest.main(SaveDataClientTest.java:54)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.roomId' [update com.infotech.entities.Device as generatedAlias0 set generatedAlias0.dispalyName = :param0, generatedAlias1.roomId = 2 where generatedAlias0.deviceName=:param1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3324)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.AbstractManipulationCriteriaQuery$1.buildCompiledQuery(AbstractManipulationCriteriaQuery.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3628)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:203)
    at com.infotech.client.SaveDataClientTest.main(SaveDataClientTest.java:54)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.roomId' [update com.infotech.entities.Device as generatedAlias0 set generatedAlias0.dispalyName = :param0, generatedAlias1.roomId = 2 where generatedAlias0.deviceName=:param1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
    ... 6 more
```

will you please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: update is not possible to multiple tables

Comment: Thanks Oleh Kurpiak,  but in what way to achieve this. can you please suggest me.

Comment: you can do two separate update statements in single transaction

Comment: ok, but can you please give me any example code.

Comment: just do two separate CriteriaUpdate statements :D

Comment: Thanks Oleh Kurpiak, but I did Not Understend. just what I want is  updating the foreign key value in  Device Table which is I asked above.

Comment: I just want to update roomId in Device table. Hear roomId is Foreign key in device table and roomId is Primary key Room Table.

Comment: from entity perspective there is no roomId property in Device object so error is correct. If you want to update foreign key to point to new Room then just select wanted room and set it to your device

Comment: Yes Oleh Kurpiak, what you Said is Correct, there is no roomId property in Device object. but, Room Object is Their in Device Object. can you please explain how select wanted room and set it to  device. can please littlie bit of code I can understand much better.

Comment: Hear , I cant able to get column name of roomId in Device table to set the update the room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
        CriteriaUpdate<Device> deviceUpdate = userBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(Device.class);
        Root<Device> deviceUpdateRoot = deviceUpdate.from(Device.class);
        
        deviceUpdate.set(deviceUpdateRoot.get("dispalyName"), "DISPLAY12345"); 
        deviceUpdate.set(deviceUpdateRoot.get("roomList").get("roomId"), 2);
    
        deviceUpdate.where(userBuilder.equal(deviceUpdateRoot.get("deviceName"), "DEVICE2"));
        int returnValue = session.createQuery(deviceUpdate).executeUpdate();
```

or this?

```
        CriteriaUpdate<Device> deviceUpdate = userBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(Device.class);
        Root<Device> deviceUpdateRoot = deviceUpdate.from(Device.class);
        
        deviceUpdate.set(deviceUpdateRoot.get("dispalyName"), "DISPLAY12345"); 
        deviceUpdate.set(deviceUpdateRoot.get("roomList"), session.getReference(Room.class, 2));
    
        deviceUpdate.where(userBuilder.equal(deviceUpdateRoot.get("deviceName"), "DEVICE2"));
        int returnValue = session.createQuery(deviceUpdate).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Hi Christian Beikov, I tried first one , but I got errors.

Comment: Thanks Christian Beikov , The Second code got worked for me ,Thank you so much.